# How to put text in front of an image while still being responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive, absolute

I'm trying to put a rating text in front of an image. I did this via `z-index`and `position: absolute`. However this text should always be on that position of the photo, now it has a static position. The text is a rating number of the title. And should be like this. How do I make this happen?

[image]

```css
.rating{
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Abril Fatface', cursive;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}

.rating-lant{
  position: absolute;
  right: 63rem;
  top: 37rem;
}

.img-title-activity{
  margin-left: 10rem;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <p class="rating rating-lant">7.5</p>
      <img src="./assets/img/Lantaarnopsteker-title@288x.png" alt="Lantaarnopsteker" width="584" height="264" class="img-title-activity">
</div>
```

Comment: Try adding `position:relative` to container, this will make rating take a position according to the container

Comment: that did the job, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a container div for the image and the heading text and set the position of the container div to relative. By setting giving margin top of 50%, it will bring it to the center of the image.

Here is an example I did for you
https://codepen.io/harsimarriar96/pen/WyOgVb

CSS

```
.image-with-text {
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="image-with-text">
  <h1>Text on image</h1>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/800x800" />
</div>
```